# GLSL: scalar vs vector performance

Tags: performance, opengl, glsl, vectorization

All modern GPUs have scalar architecture, but shading languages offer a variety of vector and matrix types. I would like to know, how does scalarization or vectorization of GLSL source code affect performance. For example, let's define some "scalar" points:

```
float p0x, p0y, p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, p3x, p3y, p4x, p4y;
p0x = 0.0f; p0y = 0.0f;
p1x = 0.0f; p1y = 0.61f;
p2x = 0.9f; p2y = 0.4f;
p3x = 1.0f; p3y = 1.0f;
```

and their vector equivalents:

```
vec2 p0 = vec2(p0x, p0y);
vec2 p1 = vec2(p1x, p1y);
vec2 p2 = vec2(p2x, p2y);
vec2 p3 = vec2(p3x, p3y);
```

Having these points, which of the following mathematically equivalent pieces of code will run faster?

Scalar code:

```
position.x = -p0x*pow(t-1.0,3.0)+p3x*(t*t*t)+p1x*t*pow(t-1.0,2.0)*3.0-p2x*(t*t)*(t-1.0)*3.0;
position.y = -p0y*pow(t-1.0,3.0)+p3y*(t*t*t)+p1y*t*pow(t-1.0,2.0)*3.0-p2y*(t*t)*(t-1.0)*3.0;
```

or it's vector equivalent:

```
position.xy = -p0*pow(t-1.0,3.0)+p3*(t*t*t)+p1*t*pow(t-1.0,2.0)*3.0-p2*(t*t)*(t-1.0)*3.0;
```

?

Or will they run equivalently fast on modern GPUs?

The above code is only an example. Real-life examples of such "vectorizable" code may perform much heavier computations with much more input variables coming from global `in`s, uniforms and vertex attributes.

Comment: Does it matter? The vector forms are much more readable than the unvectored forms. Do what actually makes sense and let the compiler do its job.

Comment: As @NicolBolas has mentioned, the glsl optimiser does a lot of optimisation before compiling. So I would guess both the code will be optimised to the same form. Or, doing a benchmark can give you more info.

Comment: @NicolBolas: yes, it does matter, especially because you don't know which drivers the user will have. Sure, 80% of the time I don't care, but for the 20% when I needed the performance I asked myself the same question (and couldn't find a definite answer).

Comment: @ybungalobill That's kind of a trap though. Because it's equally valid to assume that one driver might have a different idea about how to optimize the given code than another, especially for different GPUs. The vectorized version might be faster on one GPU, and the Scalarized version might be faster on another. There's no general purpose answer, and like NicolBolas said, it's probably best just to code for readability and let the driver do its own optimizations. If you really desperately need performance beyond that, you'll be stuck benchmarking for specific GPUs and writing separate Shaders.

Comment: You won't find a definite answer, because it's impossible. NVIDIA's GPUs for a period of time were designed as vector processors, modern chips from both AMD and NV are scalar, with AMD taking a hybrid approach and NV being purely scalar. But they could up and decide tomorrow to change this all over again if they wanted to. None of this should truly matter though, because the driver author darn well better know how their hardware works and perform trivial vectorization as needed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to do benchmarking on all the varieties of Systems (i.e. GPUs) that you believe could be used with this code, and work out which ones are faster with the Vectorized code, and which are faster with the Scalarized code. Then you'd write both versions of the code (or, more likely, the multitude of versions), and write runtime logic to switch which version is being used based on which GPU/drivers are being used.

That, of course, is a huge hassle. Most programmers won't do that; GPGPU programmers usually have only a single server/GPU node type that they work with, so their code will be specifically tailored to only a single architecture. Meanwhile, at AAA Game Studios (which are the only other place which would have the budget and manpower to tackle that kind of task) they usually just let NVidia and AMD sort out that magic on their end, where NVidia/AMD will write better, more optimized versions of the Shaders used by those games, add them to their drivers, and tell the drivers to substitute in the better Shaders instead of whatever Gearbox/Bethesda/whomever tried to load.

The important thing is, for *your* use case, your best bet is to focus on making the code more maintainable; that will save you way more time, and will make your program run better, than any "premature optimization" will (which, let's be clear, is basically what you're doing).

Answer (score 3):

The vectorised version is highly unlikely to be slower - in the worst case, it will probably just be replaced with the scalar version by the compiler anyway.

It may however be faster. Whether it will be faster largely depends on whether the code branches - if there are no branches, it is easier to feed the processing to multiple SIMD lanes than with code which branches. Compilers are pretty smart, and might be able to figure out that the scalar version can also be sent to multiple SIMD lanes ... but the compiler is more likely to be able to do its job to the best of its ability using the vectorised version. They're also smart enough to sometimes keep the SIMD lanes fed in the presence of limited branching, so even with branching code you are probably better off using the vectorised version.